# Angular 5 Pipe, {updateOn:'blur'} not updating model as expected

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I've created a custom pipe in Angular 5 that updates the display of an input field on blur.

The value of the input field is converted and displayed, but the value of the model is not updated properly. This is the functionality I am expecting, is there a way to achieve this with a pipe?

[Stackblitz - Link to Sample Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pipe-update-issue?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)

**Steps to Reproduce the issue.**

Remove the existing value and type in any number and click outside the field. (Eg: 242235.34234)

[image: Screenshot of issue]

The input and the model values do not match.

***HTML Code:***

```
<h1>Currency Pipe</h1>

<div>
  Input:
  <input type="text" [ngModel]="inputValue | currency" name="inputValue"
    [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn:'blur'}" (ngModelChange)="inputValue=$event"/>
</div>

<div>{{ inputValue }}</div>
```

***Angular Pipe:***

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import * as accounting from 'accounting';

@Pipe({
  name: 'currency'
})
export class CurrencyPipe implements PipeTransform {

  private format = { precision: 2, thousand: ',', decimal: '.' };

  transform(value: string): any {

    let formattedValue = accounting.unformat(value);
    return accounting.formatNumber(formattedValue, this.format);
  }

}
```

Comment: Shared link of stackblitz is broken. Can you please correct it?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're adding a pipe for the input but not the output? {{ inputValue | currency }}

Comment: Thank you for the alternative, but my concern is that, without adding the pipe to the output; the model value should be automatically updated. The currency pipe provided to the input should update the value of the model on blur.
The input value will be bound to the model value right?

Comment: no, the pipe does not update the original value. It pipes the value to a different output. its the whole point of the pipe, according to your code. You don't want it to be 2 decimal places, otherwise the calculations might go off

Comment: In fact, i would say, reverse it. Don't pipe the input, just the output.

Comment: No, it updates the model, but not immediately.

Try these steps:

1. Clear the field and enter a big value. Eg: 12345
2. Edit the value and click outside, the model updates accordingly with formatted value.

Comment: Youre thinking of getter setter. A pipe should not update the value. Debug inputValue and you will find the value has not changed.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your inputs. I understand that only user input is responsible for model update. What I want is that the pipe update the model value automatically. Is there a way to do this? This is the functionality I want. I've updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

As i stated before, you shouldn't be using a pipe to morph the value. Instead, try a getter/setter.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as accounting from 'accounting';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  private $inputValue;
  private format = { precision: 2, thousand: ',', decimal: '.' };

  set inputValue(value){
    let formattedValue = accounting.unformat(value);
    this.$inputValue = accounting.formatNumber(formattedValue, this.format);
  } 

  get inputValue(){ return this.$inputValue; }
}
```

and remove all the pipe stuff from the html.

Comment: Thank you for this, it is good when I have only one field.
In my application I have many fields right now, across many pages. Is there any way this could be used as a reusable component? Will looking into converting this as a directive help?

Comment: That is up to you. Angular can be as easy or as complex as you want it. Having a million getter setters might not look nice, but its easy to understand, for me anyway. But to each his own

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. Will look into the possibilities and update. :)