# Angular pipes with reactive forms: Apply only on blur

Tags: angular, pipe

I am trying to apply a pipe for my input which is built with the reactive forms

```
 <input nxInput required type='text'  [value]="billingLetterForm.get('liabilityPercentage').value | percentage"  formControlName='liabilityPercentage'  />
```

This works fine, however, how do I apply the pipe only on the `blur` event

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53688946/angular-5-pipe-updateonblur-not-updating-model-as-expected) thread but this actual solution for the template-driven form not for the reactive forms

One workaround I found is write a custom function on `blur` and apply the pipe from here but this actually modifies the input value I don't think its good solution any cleaner solution for this??

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Observable bases on blur event from that field to limit the frequency of value updates.

The simple way would be adding your field as a ViewChild to parent component.
This allows to create an observable from an event where the target is the input you're interested in:

```html
<input nxInput #liabilityPctInput ...>
```

```js
class ComponentWithLiabilityPctInput {
...
@ViewChild('liabilityPctInput')
liabilityPctInput;

ngOnInit() {
    let liabilityPctInputBlur$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(this.liabilityPctInput, 'blur');
    this.valueThatChangesOnBlur$ = liabilityPctInputBlur$
        .pipe(map(() => billingLetterForm.get('liabilityPercentage').value));
  }

}
```

And then you can use it in the template with `async` pipe:

```html
<input nxInput #liabilityPctInput [value]="valueThatChangesOnBlur$ | async | percentage"...>
```